# Why won't CURRENT_TIMESTAMP work on mysqlworkbench?

Tags: mysql, debugging, mysql-workbench

I want to retrieve current times when post's created and updated.  In a tutorial I'm following, the author uses `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` without the `()` but that didn't work me, it gave me `std::exception`.

Below I'm doing `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` but that doesn't work.  I've also read online and tried `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but that also doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

[image]

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of `created_at` and `updated_at`?

Comment: @Zendy I'm using Laravel.  I just posted a snippet of code that of which displays data types.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Could you also post your SQL query for retrieving the post?

Comment: @Zendy `SELECT * FROM tutorialreact.blogs;`

Comment: I don't see anything related to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in your table definition or query. Could you edit the question with step by step of things that you trying to do?
Link to the tutorial would help to.

Comment: @Zendy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dyl1wG_Wf7o&index=3&list=PLTXFz3WKxvNJZo1T0-ypVBWD0MfJtshav start at 6:24

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189786/discussion-between-greyskies-and-zendy).

Comment: What is `timestamps()`? There's not enough here to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you tried to insert `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` from GUI input which is wrong because it tries to parse it as a string to date.

I suggest you insert it with SQL query instead.

```
INSERT INTO blogs 
    (id, name, body, created_at, updated_at) 
VALUES 
    (null, 'this is name', 'this is body', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

Answer (score 0):

> In a tutorial I'm following, the author uses CURRENT_TIMESTAMP without the ()

Based on your results and on a few educated guesses relating to what's happening in that video clip, this appears to be a feature of Sequel Pro, the database client the tutorial presenter is using, rather than of the MySQL database itself. And instead of Sequel Pro, you're using MySQL Workbench, a completely different piece of software.

The MySQL feature of a very similar name indeed is a function call with a `()` after it, so that's something else.

> but that didn't work me, it gave me std::exception.

That particular symptom sounds like a bug to me, though there's no real reason to expect Workbench to accept a non-date (or even an arbitrary expression) in a date/time field.

It's just not possible to accept input like that unambiguously, without the benefit of nice things like quotation marks and field name delimiters, which is what you get by writing the full `INSERT` statement yourself, bypassing the Workbench widgets. You'll need that for Zendy's good workaround of using the MySQL `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` function instead.

> Below I'm doing CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() but that doesn't work. I've also read online and tried DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but that also doesn't work.

Likely these are limitations of the Workbench interface. It's struggling to decide whether you are giving it *verbatim* strings to store in the table, or expressions with function calls. And, in fairness, and again, it doesn't have enough information to deduce that for 100% certain.

That's why crafting your own SQL statements is usually better. It's the only way to specifically state exactly what you are trying to do.